# Text to Speech C#

Tags: c#

So I'm just a uni student who's enjoying programming (1st year) and I've decided to try out some new features.

I came across the speech synthesizer and its reallt interesting, but i have one problem.

Say if I said

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

Is there a way that I could get the program to say that without having to add

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
s.Speak("Hello");
```

?

Like I'm wondering if I am able to have my program speak whatever I type without adding extra code

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you could do that. But what you can try is creating a static method that takes a `string` value and prints "Hello" on to the console and use the TTS engine, like

```
static void PrintAndSpeak(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    s.Speak(message);
}
```

And then use the method inside the entry point:

```
PrintAndSpeak("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that would take in your string. That method would print and read the message.

Example (pseudocode)

```
public void writeAndTalk(string message){
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    s.Speak(message);
}
```

And you then use the method wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a type to do this for you. Something like:

```
public class TextAndSpeech
{
    private readonly WhateverSIs s;

    public TextAndSpeech(WhateverSIs s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public Spurt(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        s.Speak(message);
    }
}
```

I have no idea what type `s` is that you're using, so replace `WhateverSIs` with the actual type.

Using it would look something like:

```
var spurter = new TextAndSpeech(new WhateverSIs());
spurter.Spurt("Hello");
spurter.Spurt("Another thing.");
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry I should have clarified what everything meant. WhateverSIs = SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();

Comment: But what if i want to use it alot? Like i have a whole program with WriteLines and i want it to read each writeline?

Comment: @JackMorrison Just use `spurter.Spurt()` for each of them. You can keep a reference to the `TextAndSpeech` object in a class member variable if that helps you reference it in other places.